# Question about Residues at Poles

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I've been asked to find the residues of the following function;

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{(z^2+1)(z-1)^2}$$

So, I've got that the singularities are $\pm i$ and $1$, with order 1 and 2 respectively.

I was hoping to use the following theorem;

> if $f(z)$ can be expressed as $f(z) = \frac{\phi(z)}{(z-z_0)^m}$, with $\phi(z)$ analytic and non-zero at $z_0$, then;
>   $$res_{z \rightarrow z_0} f(z) = \frac{ \phi^{(m-1)}(z_0)}{(m-1)!}$$

So, for the residue at $z = 1$, I can do the following;
$$\phi(z) = \frac{1}{(z^2 + 1)}$$ (clearly analytic for z = 1), and then have the following;

$$res_{z \rightarrow 1} f(z) = \frac{ \phi^{(2-1)}(1)}{(2-1)!} = \frac{-2 \times 1}{(1^2 + 1)^2} = \frac{-2}{4} = \frac{-1}{2}$$

So, the residue for $z = 1$ is $\frac{-1}{2}$.

Now, when I try it for the pole at $z = i$, I get the following;
$$\phi(z) = \frac{1}{(z-1)^2}$$ (clearly analytic for z = i), and then have the following;

$$res_{z \rightarrow i} f(z) = \frac{ \phi^{(1-1)}(1)}{(1-1)!} = \frac{\phi(i)}{1} = \frac{1}{(i-1)^2} = \frac{i}{2}$$

So, we have the residue at $z = i$ as $\frac{i}{2}$. Using similar working, we can see that the residue at $z = -i$ = $\frac{-i}{2}$.

For verification, I wanted to check my answers using Wolfram; [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=res%201%20%5C%20%28%28z%5E2%2b1%29%2a%28z-1%29%5E2%29)

However, in this answer, I apparently get the residues at $z = \pm i$ as $\frac{1}{4}$. I can't really see how this works, and I'm a bit stumped as to where to proceed from here. I can't see anything wrong with my methods - I don't think I've misread my textbook, at least, so I'm a little unsure as to where I went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps easier using Cauchy's Residue Theorem

$$\lim_{z\to i}(z-i)f(z)=\lim_{z\to i}\frac1{(z+i)(z-1)^2}=\frac1{2i(1-i)^2}=\frac14$$

and likewise for the other pole in $\;z=-i\;$...

The problem in your development is that in fact

$$\phi(z)=\frac1{(z+i)(z-1)^2}$$

and not what you wrote.

Comment: Why is it that both theorems provide differing answers??

Comment: Check again my answer, @Jack

Comment: Aha!! I see it now, thank you!!

In that case, in the future, if I wanted to use my method, would I have to break up terms such as $(z^2 + 1)$ into its factors??

Comment: Always, @Jack...but this is not always as nice to do as in this case. Either develop the function in a Laurent series around a given pole or else use Cauchy's formula for the residue, even if that means to take the limit of differentials.